# how to set data text value and data text field in drop down list control in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

This is my code dropdown list

```xml
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GroupName">
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"  Width="100%" Height="10%" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="GroupName"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:551680A3622135F7C7A89A2044CE6B6E_12 2014\20 12 14\BACKUP 19 NEW\19 NEW\SCHOOLMANAGEMENT\SCHOOLMANAGEMENT\APP_DATA\TCS_SCHOOL.MDFConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [GroupName FROM [Group1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
  </EditItemTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblgroup" runat="server"   Text='<%#Eval("GroupName") %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"  Width="100%" Height="10%" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="GroupName"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:551680A3622135F7C7A89A2044CE6B6E_12 2014\20 12 14\BACKUP 19 NEW\19 NEW\SCHOOLMANAGEMENT\SCHOOLMANAGEMENT\APP_DATA\TCS_SCHOOL.MDFConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [GroupName] FROM [Group1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want groupname in datatextfield and groupid in datavaluefield.

How do I do this in C#? How do I bind that two values to dropdownlist in C#??

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have set groupName to both dataText field and dataValue field. Maybe thats the problem? Try to Set
 groupId in the dataValue field.

Comment: You are guessing some thing, aren't you? Then this type of reply should be added in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

include GroupId in your Select command then set DataValueField="GroupId".

Hope it helps,
Alessandro